# Paypal transaction to me is verified (by API), but my account balance is $0.00

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

Paypal transaction yesterday was verified (by API (https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/)), but my account balance was $0.00.

Today the same API answers me ---->  ["name"]=> string(19) "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID" ["message"]=> string(39) "The requested resource ID was not found" ["information_link"]=> string(54) "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors" ["debug_id"]=> string(13) "b39d1f444064e"

And balance is $0 again. How to fix it, there in my online store are verified payments, they get "verified" status during payment, by API query.. what to do now? Where to search the problem?

(Before that the Sandbox version worked fine).

Payment execution:

```
if($test_mode_paypal)
        $execute_url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/'.$pay_key.'/execute';
    else
        $execute_url = 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/'.$pay_key.'/execute';

    $header = array();
    $header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
    $header[] = 'Accept: application/json';
    $header[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken;
    $data ='{
      "payer_id":"'.$payer_id.'"
    }';
    //open connection
    $curl = curl_init();
    //set connection properties
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $execute_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    //execute post
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    //close connection
    curl_close($curl);

    $result = json_decode($response);


    $response_arr = array();
    if($result->state == 'approved')
    {
        $response_arr['status'] = 'ok';
        $response_arr['message'] = $response;
        return $response_arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you [created the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_create) but you never [executed it](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_execute).

Comment: No, that doesn't help. I've added /execute too, now I get  "state":"approved", but payment still doesn't made.

Comment: I've edited question, there is how the function looks like.

Comment: Maybe problem occures when I create payment? I create it in this way: 

`$curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LP73NDI44T29238WB1316137"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
 'Accept: application/json',
 'Content-Type: application/json'
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);`

Comment: if I have errors in "create" or  "execute" functions, then why I get approved. 
I think maybe curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false); have to get true value, but then I get error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
props.js:246 Uncaught Error: Request to post https://aylkerp.am/successful-payment-post-notify failed with 500 error. Correlation id: unknown

{
    "message": "Server Error"
}
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http.js:114)";

<https://aylkerp.am/successful-payment-post-notify> is my EXECUTE_URL: url in "paypal.Button.render" function

Comment: If you're getting approved, and not an error back from the API, then it's working.  If you aren't seeing the money then you must be looking at the wrong account.  Make sure you're signed in to the same sandbox account that you pulled the API credentials from as the seller account.